# how to preg_match in php for numeric with fixed range?

Tags: php, preg-match

how can I preg_match in php for numeric with fixed range?

I want to allow 8 digit number in text box without starting of 0.

Eg-**12345678**

The following is my piece of code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    if(empty($_POST["phone"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your phone number</label></p>';
 }
 else{
     if(!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{8}$/",$PhNum))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only 8 digit numbers are allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is just slightly off, and you should be expecting *seven* digits after the initial digit which is not zero:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{7}$/", $PhNum)) {
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only 8 digit numbers are allowed</label></p>';
}
```

Conceptually:

```
[1-9][0-9]{7}  <-- seven digits, for a total of 8 digits
^^^ one digit
```

Comment: thanks sir, but still not correct. When i enter 12345678 or 1234567, it still show "Only 8 digit numbers are allowed". Should not show message if I enter 12345678, am I right ?